# arduino code compile issue trying to store serial data from certain lables as a variable

Tags: arduino

I am trying to build a code in arduino, and am having an issue with getting it to compile. I am trying to build a monitor for my MPPT controller, it outputs via serial. i am able to receive the serial data to the pc through the arduino, and am now having an issue getting it to save values from the incomming serial information and store its value as a variable that i can call to perform other functions.

the serial data incomming into the pc is always the same, and is formatted like this

```
PID 0xA042
FW 123
SER# HQ155154LPY
V 0
I 0
VPV 0
PPV 0
CS 0
ERR 0
LOAD OFF
IL 0
H19 4438
H20 0
H21 0
H22 38
H23 136
HSDS 74
Checksum
```

and i need the values from the following fields

```
V, I,VPV,PPV,LOAD,H19,IL
```

the information is sent from the controller like this

```
Message format
The device transmits blocks of data at 1 second intervals. Each field is sent using the following format:
<Newline><Field-Label><Tab><Field-Value>

The identifiers are defined as follows:
Identifier                     Meaning

<Newline>                     A carriage return followed by a line feed (0x0D, 0x0A).
<Field-Label>                An arbitrary length label that identifies the field. Where applicable, this will be the same as the label that is used on the LCD.
<Tab>                           A horizontal tab (0x09).
<Field-Value>                The ASCII formatted value of this field. The number of characters transmitted depends on the magnitude and sign of the value.


Data integrity

The statistics are grouped in blocks with a checksum appended. The last field in a block will always be "Checksum". The value is a single byte, and will not necessarily be a printable ASCII character. The modulo 256 sum of all bytes in a block will equal 0 if there were no transmission errors. Multiple blocks are sent containing different fields.
```

this is the first time i have actualy tried to use serial for something other than simple debug/operation messages running in the code.

the code

```
        /*
           Odroid-SHOW MPPT Intrface Module

           Reads information from MPPT controllers and displays it on the LCD, also outputs the information via SERIAL @ 9600 BAUD

     * **********PINOUTS********
        MPPT Controller:
         ________________________
        |    4    3    2    1    |
        |    .    .    .    .    |
        |   VCC  TX   RX   GND   |
        | (RED) (YEL)(WHI)(BLK)  |
        |        _______         |
        |_______|       |________|

    Odroid SHOW:

    5V - To VCC (RED) Pin (4)
    A4 - To TX  (YEL) Pin (3)
    A5 - To RX  (WHI) Pin (2)
   GND - To GND (BLK) Pin (1)



*/

const char version[] = {"1.0 27/04/2017"};


//Below is the required Library inclusions

  #include <SoftwareSerial.h>
  #include <SPI.h>
  #include <Wire.h>
  #include "TimerOne.h"
  #include <Adafruit_GFX.h>
  #include <ODROID_Si1132.h>
  #include <ODROID_Si70xx.h>
  #include <Adafruit_ILI9340.h>




//Below is the required Pin Defines and links for the TFT

  #define _sclk 13
  #define _miso 12
  #define _mosi 11
  #define _cs 10
  #define _dc 9
  #define _rst 8
  Adafruit_ILI9340 tft = Adafruit_ILI9340(_cs, _dc, _rst);
  ODROID_Si70xx si7020;
  ODROID_Si1132 si1132;



// Settings below are to control the Backlight brightness and rotation of the Odroid-SHOW LCD Display
  uint8_t ledPin = 5;
  uint8_t pwm = 255;
  uint8_t textSize = 2;
  uint8_t rotation = 1; //0 = Portrait, 1 = Landscape




//Below sets up the SoftwareSerial ports so that the arduino can receive information from the MPPT Controller aswell as pass its information through to the hardware UART
  SoftwareSerial MPPTSERIAL(A4, A5); // RX, TX



void setup() {
// initialize the TFT and the digital pins for TFT backlight control
  tft.begin();
  si1132.begin();
  initPins();
  delay(50);


// Open serial communications on hardware UART and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  delay(50);



//Below Prints the module Version information to both the Serial monitor and the TFT  
  Serial.println("Odroid-SHOW MPPT Intrface Module");
  Serial.print("Module Firmware Version ");
  Serial.println(version);
  tft.fillScreen(ILI9340_BLACK);
  tft.setRotation(rotation);
  tft.setTextSize(textSize);
  tft.setCursor(25, 25);
  tft.print("Odroid-SHOW");
  tft.setCursor(25, 45);
  tft.print("MPPT Intrface Module");
  tft.setCursor(25, 85);
  tft.print("Module Firmware Version");
  tft.setCursor(25, 105);
  tft.print(version);
  delay(2500);

// set the data rate for the SoftwareSerial port and print to TFT when initialized
  MPPTSERIAL.begin(19200);
  Serial.println("MPPT Serial Connection Initialized");
  tft.setRotation(rotation);
  tft.setTextSize(textSize);
  tft.setCursor(25, 145);
  tft.print("MPPT Serial");
  tft.setCursor(25, 165);
  tft.print("Connection Initialized");
  delay(2500);
  tft.fillScreen(ILI9340_BLACK);
}


void loop() {

 if (MPPTSERIAL.available())
  {
    char inComing = MPPTSERIAL.read();  //read the available byte into a variable
      String BattVoltage = getValue(inComing, "/n", 3).toString();
      String PVCurrent = getValue(inComing, "/n", 4).toString();
      String PVVoltage = getValue(inComing, "/n", 5).toString();
    Serial.println(BattVoltage);  //output the Battery Voltage to Serial Monitor
    Serial.println(PVCurrent);  //output the PV Charge Current to Serial Monitor    
    Serial.println(BattVoltage);  //output the PV Voltage to Serial Monitor
    tft.setRotation(rotation);
    tft.setTextSize(textSize);
    tft.setCursor(25, 25);  
    tft.print("Battery Voltage:")(BattVoltage);  //output Battery Voltage to TFT
    tft.setCursor(25, 145);
    tft.print ("PV Current:")(PVCurrent);  //output PV Charge Current to TFT
    tft.setCursor(25, 165);
    tft.print("PV Voltage:")(PVVoltage);  //output PV Voltage to TFT
    tft.fillScreen(ILI9340_BLACK);
  }
  if (Serial.available()) {
    MPPTSERIAL.write(Serial.read());
  }
}



String getValue(String data, char separator, int index)
{
    int found = 0;
    int strIndex[] = { 0, -1 };
    int maxIndex = data.length() - 1;

    for (int i = 0; i <= maxIndex && found <= index; i++) {
        if (data.charAt(i) == separator || i == maxIndex) {
            found++;
            strIndex[0] = strIndex[1] + 1;
            strIndex[1] = (i == maxIndex) ? i+1 : i;
        }
    }
    return found > index ? data.substring(strIndex[0], strIndex[1]) : "";
}


//Below is the various Function Calls 
    //This is the Backlight PWM control pin settings
      void initPins(){
        pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
        analogWrite(ledPin, pwm);
      }
```

The IDE highlights these lines as the source of the error

```
String BattVoltage = getValue(inComing, "/n", 3).toString();
          String PVCurrent = getValue(inComing, "/n", 4).toString();
          String PVVoltage = getValue(inComing, "/n", 5).toString();
```

and that is giving me this error

```
converting to 'String' from initializer list would use explicit constructor 'String::String(char)'
```

from what i can gather, i may need to change it from a srting to an INT or a CHAR, but all the examples i have tried and just guessed out of hope have failed.

any pointers?

Jason

Comment: The second parameter of `getValue()` is declared as a char; you're passing a string.  Write it as `'\n'` instead.

Comment: hmmm, ok. thanks. i tried that and it now throws this error

        **** 'getValue' was not declared in this scope ****

however, it is declared as a function isnt it? atleast the way i read it it is.

Comment: It isn't declared yet at the point you use it.  Either move the function up, or put a forward declaration towards the top of the file.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. In the code I have a function (void initPins) that is below the loop function and outside of it. Yet it is called in the setup. And is not throwing an error. Is what I'm trying to do not been declared as *local variable = (function call)?

Comment: I guess it's letting you get by without a declaration of `initPins()` because there are no parameters whose types have to match between caller & callee.  I would guess that you're at least getting a warning about that, check the compiler output.

Comment: ok, i tried shifting the function to above the loop and above the setup and i get a different error. *****expected identifier before string constant*****. i guess i should ask, where should my functions be located? before setup, between setup and loop, after loop? i have tried to look into how to declare the getValue call, but my understanding is that (using this line as an example) *****String BattVoltage = getValue(inComing, "/n", 3).toString();****** battvoltage is the name of the string and it is equal to the value returned by the getValue call. but to my understanding,

Comment: the getvalue in that line is declaring it as a local variable. i am assuming that it is using the conditions in the brackets as to where to get the value from, in this case its getting the value from inComming (a function in the MPPTSERIAL.read) and is looking for newline #3 and then saving the returned value into the string BattVoltage. am i on the right track? if so, i am lost as to where the error is.

Comment: I'm not talking about local variables, I'm talking about the `getValue` function itself.  Either the function, or a forward declaration of the function (which would look like `String getValue(String data, char separator, int index);`) should appear ahead of any function (such as `loop`) that calls it.  The compiler does not otherwise know what types the parameters are supposed to be.

Comment: ok, im still lost. i put that forward recommendation at the top of the code, (although i assume its meant to be "\n" opposed to "char seperator") and then it just gives me an error ****** expected identifier before string constant****** but i am still getting an error if i move the entire function call to the top of the code. i just dont understand why. what is the identifier that it is looking for before string constant? i simply just dont understand where the issue is. to me, reading it it makes sense. but clearly something is not right.

Comment: No, I meant exactly what I said.  The purpose of a declaration is to specify types for a function's parameters; actual values such as `"\n"` (which isn't even a valid value for a `char` parameter, as I mentioned before) aren't supplied until you actually call the function.

Comment: then wouldnt i just need ****  String getValue;  ****?

Comment: That would declare `getValue` as a String variable, not as a function.

Comment: ok, so how do i forward declare it as a function? i have tried "int, #define, char" but all i get are errors. i just dont know what i need to do to declare it.

Comment: Just like I said before `String getValue(String data, char separator, int index);` - the same thing as the definition of the function, but with a semicolon instead of the body of the function.

Comment: and it throws this error back ******converting to 'String' from initializer list would use explicit constructor 'String::String(char)'*****

Comment: That's because you're passing a char for the first parameter, but have declared it as a String.  How are you expecting to find the 3rd, 4th, or 5th newline within a single character?

Comment: i dont know, i am just using what i can peice together from my research online to get the desired outcome. what i want it to do is take in the serial data, and save the value presented on specific lines. i originaly thought of getting it to look for a "keyword" and then have it save the value associated with it. but someone suggested that the newline method would be better and use less memory. 

so, in the code where i have told it "\n",3 would it not look for the 3rd newline command and save the value from there?